Error getting started with first JavaFX app: HelloFX
I'm a beginner programmer. I ran into an error while following the Getting Started Tutorial on creating my first JavaFX app and I'm not really sure what's wrong.
This is the error message that is returned when running my MainApp.java:
"Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method."
7:34:13 PM: Executing ':MainApp.main()'...

> Task :compileJava
> Task :processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :classes

> Task :MainApp.main() FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.9/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.
3 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 1 up-to-date
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:118)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:465)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1147)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:901)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1570)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3361)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3324)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3292)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3264)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3240)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3233)
    at org.openjfx.MainApp.start(MainApp.java:14)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:847)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:484)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:457)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application org.openjfx.MainApp

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':MainApp.main()'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-22\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 1s
7:34:14 PM: Execution finished ':MainApp.main()'.

I'm using JavaFX 17.0.12 on JDK 22.0.1 with Gradle and IntelliJ:
Project Structure

build.gradle
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.1.0'
}

group = 'org.example'
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.openjfx:javafx-controls:17.0.12'
    implementation 'org.openjfx:javafx-fxml:17.0.12'
    testImplementation platform('org.junit:junit-bom:5.10.0')
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter'
}

javafx {
    version = '17.0.12'
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml' ]
}

application {
    mainClass = 'org.openjfx.MainApp'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDir 'src/main/resources'
        }
    }
}

build folder


And this is the code:
MainApp.java
package org.openjfx;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class MainApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("scene.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("styles.css").toExternalForm());

        stage.setTitle("JavaFX and Gradle");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}

Warnings:


FXMLController.java
package org.openjfx;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class FXMLController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label label;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        String javaVersion = System.getProperty("java.version");
        String javafxVersion = System.getProperty("javafx.version");
        label.setText("Hello, JavaFX " + javafxVersion + "\nRunning on Java " + javaVersion + ".");
    }
}

scene.fxml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>


<StackPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="org.openjfx.FXMLController">
    <children>
        <Label fx:id="label" text="Label" />
    </children>
</StackPane>

styles.css
.label {
    -fx-text-fill: blue;
}


Tried:
Running via "./gradlew run" and got same error.

Using
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("sample.fxml")); as suggested here and got same error


Post entire error message as text, not image.

How did you create this project? Did you use IntelliJ’s project template for JavaFX? And, what version of IntelliJ?

Hello, thank you for your response. (1) I edited the original post to contain the full error message. (2) I created this project by going to [New -> Project -> New Java Project {Name: HelloFX, Build System: Gradle, JDK: Oracle OpenJDK 22.0.1, Gradle DSL: Groovy} -> Create], and then adding the JavaFX SDK which I put on my C:\ drive in [File -> Project Structure -> Libraries] and then added it to VM options with [Run -> Edit Config -> Modify options -> add VM options: "--module-path "C:\javafx-sdk-17.0.12\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml"]

Also it's IntelliJ 2024.1.2 (Community Edition)

It is odd that you are using a package name of org.openjfx as seen in that screenshot of project folder structure, such as where you store your .fxml file. You should be using your own package name. I have no idea if that affects your problem or not.

Possibly related: JavaFX and maven: NullPointerException: Location is required

What is in the build folder? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61531317/how-do-i-determine-the-correct-path-for-fxml-files-css-files-images-and-other

Gradle reports Task :MainApp.main() FAILED. What happens if you execute the :run task (either from the terminal with ./gradlew run or via IntelliJ) instead of the :MainApp.main() task?

@James_D It's just normal gradle stuff. I edited the post to show the build folder contents.

@Slaw "./gradlew run" gives the same error

@BasilBourque It does seem similar. I tried the accepted answer and it didn't work though... (Edited the post to include a "tried" section)

IMO it is not worth your time to try to debug your issue.  Instead, just follow Basil's answer and start with an app that works.  If you really must remove the modularity from it (after it is working), then delete the module-info.java, download the JavaFX SDK, and configure the VM parameters manually as per instructions at openjfx.io.  If you do so, then make sure they are actual VM parameters and not runtime arguments.

Use explicit Application class
This page on CodeRanch.com recommends against using getClass when obtaining a resource in your new FXMLLoader line. Try changing getClass().getResource to MainApp.class.getResource. I do not know if that will solve your problem; just a guess.
Let IntelliJ create your JavaFX project
Also, you have not indicated if you actually used the current version of IntelliJ to create a JavaFX project using its provided project template. I  suspect not.
I just did so, creating a new project in IntelliJ 2024.2.1 Preview using JavaFX template via the JavaFX plugin 242.21829.15, in Java 22.0.2 on macOS Sonoma.
package work.basil.example.exfx22gradle;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloApplication extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start ( Stage stage ) throws IOException
    {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader( HelloApplication.class.getResource( "hello-view.fxml" ) );
        Scene scene = new Scene( fxmlLoader.load( ) , 320 , 240 );
        stage.setTitle( "Hello!" );
        stage.setScene( scene );
        stage.show( );
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        launch( );
    }
}

The build.gradle file:
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.javamodularity.moduleplugin' version '1.8.12'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.13'
    id 'org.beryx.jlink' version '2.25.0'
}

group 'work.basil.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    junitVersion = '5.10.2'
}

sourceCompatibility = '22'
targetCompatibility = '22'

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

application {
    mainModule = 'work.basil.example.exfx22gradle'
    mainClass = 'work.basil.example.exfx22gradle.HelloApplication'
}

javafx {
    version = '22.0.1'
    modules = ['javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml']
}

dependencies {

    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitVersion}")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitVersion}")
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

jlink {
    imageZip = project.file("${buildDir}/distributions/app-${javafx.platform.classifier}.zip")
    options = ['--strip-debug', '--compress', '2', '--no-header-files', '--no-man-pages']
    launcher {
        name = 'app'
    }
}

jlinkZip {
    group = 'distribution'
}

The module-info.java file:
module work.basil.example.exfx22gradle {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;


    opens work.basil.example.exfx22gradle to javafx.fxml;
    exports work.basil.example.exfx22gradle;
}

The hello-view.fxml file is located in src > main > resources > work.basil.example.exfx22gradle.
This app compiled and ran without any modifications.

Using 'MainApp.class.getResource' instead did not fix it. Letting IntelliJ create the JavaFX project works but I found the default structure very confusing for my level of knowledge. Instead, I wanted to create a non-modular project with javaFX.

@Raine I find that IntelliJ is quite good at working out the modularity and auto-editing the module-info.java file.
